# Is it possible to use c# for expressions in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have just started learning SSRS and today i went through Expressions in SSRS.

Like: "=IIF(Fields!PctComplete.Value >= 10, "Green", IIF(Fields!PctComplete.Value >= 1, "Blue", "Red"))"

It seems quite confusing and not sure what language it is in.It looks like VB but i m not a vb programmer.is it possible to use C# in expressions??

would be helpful if provided some resource.

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

It appears that custom code written directly in the report must be written in Visual Basic, however external references can utilize c#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx

Comment: i have figured it out just now and looking at your answer.anyway thanks a lot for your help @Eric